# looking for training / sound design studies

Tags: studies, training, career

Hi !

Maybe this question is a little out of place here, but this forum is maybe a way to get out of established trails... I'm studying sound design in France in an art school, along with Ircam in Paris. My profile is a little unusual, as I have an academic musical training, and did quite a lot of experimental music, while studying musicology. Currently, we have to find a few months training in a lab, school or sound design agency. I'm looking for a place where I can really get to learn, especially about interaction (with max-msp for instance), synthesis (physical model and electronics). I'm especially interested in ergonomy, scenography, architecture, sound/video, ecology... not really into video games or commercials. Anyone has suggestions ?
Thanks!

Coralie

Comment: I actually ment "placement" when I was writing about the training, as far as professionnal background is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Shoot Andy Farnell an email. You never know what might happen.

http://obiwannabe.co.uk/html/author/author.html

and check out http://groups.yahoo.com/group/sound_design/

Comment: Hi Georgi, thanks for your advice. I have to translate my resume and I'll do that!

Answer (score 1):

Hi Coralie,

I studied the MSc in Sound Design at the University of Edinburgh and it does exactly all those things you're looking for. It relies heavily on Max-MSP and the academic nature of sound as well as synthesis and sonic art. It has a huge acoustics department who do everything from acoustic data modeling to synthesis modeling of ancient instruments. They're also very interested in sound and architecture.

ps. Andy Farnell came and taught us one lesson at Edinburgh too. Think he does it annually. Nice guy.

pps Love what you guys do at IRCAM!

http://sd.caad.ed.ac.uk/mscsounddesign/

http://www.ed.ac.uk/schools-departments/edinburgh-college-art/graduate-school/taughtdegrees/msc-sound-design

best of luck, 
Nicol

Comment: Hi Nicol, sorry for my late answer. Your info looks really interesting. Although I'm looking for a professional training related to an artistic or industrial project, I think this cursus at Edinburgh seems really nice. It looks a little like the master I'm doing currently. I heard about Andy Farnell and his sound design toolkit, and I'll contact him for sure. The school informed us about this erasmus exchange very late, and I'm afraid I can't organize the  thing in time. But your info will sure be useful to me ! Maybe we can keep in touch. Sincerly yours Coralie

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for someting low-paid or apprenticeship check this website:

http://www.mandy.com/1/filmtvjobs.cfm

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't anything to offer, but why not come together and have a coffee in Paris some time. Talk about sound design and composition, your CV looks pretty interesting.